# How to convert a node to multiple relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j database that stores some information about scientific articles and their authors. I need to refactor my database in the following way, as shown in the image below. Each yellow node represents an author. Red nodes are articles. I need to remove red nodes and connect authors if they are co-authors of the same article.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**TL;TR:**

```
MATCH (a1:Author)-[:HAS_WRITTEN]-(:Article)-[:HAS_WRITTEN]-(a2:Author) MERGE (a1)-[:CO_AUTHOR]-(a2)
```

1. Fetch all author pairs connected through at least one article: `MATCH (a1:Author)-[:HAS_WRITTEN]-(:Article)-[:HAS_WRITTEN]-(a2:Author)`
2. Add CO_AUTHOR relations. You could use CREATE clause, but you would end up with duplicated relations. MERGE will ensure each relation is added only once: `MERGE (a1)-[:CO_AUTHOR]-(a2)`. See [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/)

Bare in mind that directions of the MERGE relations will be pretty arbitrary and should be ignored in queries. For example, to get all co-authors of the author "author1":

```
MATCH (a1:Author {name: "author1"})-[:CO_AUTHOR]-(a2) RETURN a2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// get articles with authors
// compare ids to remove duplicates
MATCH (auth1:Author)-[:HAS_WRITTEN]->(article:Article)<-[:HAS_WRITTEN]-(auth2:Author)
WHERE id(auth1) > id(auth2)

// delete the article node
DETACH DELETE article

// MERGE co_author relationship
MERGE (auth1)-[:CO_AUTHOR]->(auth2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this query looks long, it should do what you want efficiently:

```
MATCH (author:Author)-[r:HAS_WRITTEN]->(article:Article)
DELETE r
WITH article, COLLECT(author) AS authors
DELETE article
WITH authors
UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(authors)-2) AS i
WITH authors, i
UNWIND RANGE(i+1, SIZE(authors)-1) AS j
WITH authors[i] AS a1, authors[j] AS a2
CREATE (a1)-[:CO_AUTHOR]->(a2)
```

It first finds all the `HAS_WRITTEN` relationships and deletes them. Then it  [aggregates](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) the `authors` for each `article` and deletes the article. And then it creates a `CO_AUTHOR` relationship between every pair of co-authors (there is no need to check for existing relationships, assuming none of the relationships existed before running the query).

[CORRECTION]

The above query has a flaw, as pointed out in the comments. If the same pair of authors co-author multiple articles, then they would end up being connected by multiple `CO-AUTHOR` relationships. So, this would be a corrected solution:

```
MATCH (author:Author)-[r:HAS_WRITTEN]->(article:Article)
DELETE r
WITH article, COLLECT(author) AS authors
DELETE article
WITH authors
UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(authors)-2) AS i
WITH authors, i
UNWIND RANGE(i+1, SIZE(authors)-1) AS j
WITH authors[i] AS a1, authors[j] AS a2
MERGE (a1)-[:CO_AUTHOR]-(a2)
```

It first finds all the `HAS_WRITTEN` relationships and deletes them. Then it  [aggregates](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) the `authors` for each `article` and deletes the article. And then it uses [MERGE with an undirected relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#merge-merge-on-an-undirected-relationship) to ensure there is a single `CO_AUTHOR` relationship between every pair of co-authors. The `UNWIND` clauses are used to avoid obvious relationship duplications.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but in case two authors have written multiple articles together, this will create multiple [:CO_AUTHOR]  rels between them. So I would definitely go for a MERGE.

Comment: I've tried by this way and it seems to create multiple relationships between nodes. Anyway it could be very useful. I've built a query which count the number of multiple edges between two authors, and then it assign the number of relationships as weight. Thank you @Graphileon and @cybersam!

Comment: @Graphileon Thanks for your valid comment. I have added a `CORRECTION` to my answer.